# How do I open an existing LXD container?

Tags: lxc, lxd

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed, xfce desktop for what it's worth. I have LXD installed, with my images and containers on my large second drive, with symbolic links to said images and containers configured in `/var/lib/lxd/`. Everything works as expected.

I have now re-installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a new drive, Mate desktop for what it's worth. I have installed LXD and created the symbolic links (in `/var/lib/lxd`) to my images and containers folders on my large drive.

Neither my images nor containers are listed when using lxc list (so can't start them and use them).

Any pointers on what I need to do to get my newly installed LXD to use my pre-existing images and containers ?

Comment: Whats the output of `lxc-ls` ?

Comment: lxc1 is not installed, so I don't have access to lxc-ls. I am using LXD.

Comment: I do, and I say in my post that no containers are listed when using lxc list. I have worked it out now anyway and have posted my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anybody interested, the missing piece of the puzzle was that I had to re-use the existing lxd database, `lxd.db`.

So the steps for me to use my pre-existing LXD containers on a fresh install are:-

Install LXD

```
sudo apt-get install lxd
```

Delete the `containers` and `images` directories

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/lxd/containers
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/lxd/images
```

Create symbolic links to my pre-existing `containers` and `images` directories.

```
sudo ln -s /media/sda10/lxd/containers /var/lib/lxd/containers
sudo ln -s /media/sda10/lxd/images /var/lib/lxd/images
```

Mount my original install partition and copy the lxd.db file from my original install onto my new install

```
sudo cp /mnt/var/lib/lxd/lxd.db /var/lib/lxd/lxd.db
```

My containers now show up when I list them and run as expected.

NOTE : I have multiple installations on multiple partitions, and I leap frog between new versions of Ubuntu as they become available, and don't erase an older version until I am happy. It's really easy to do and has just become second nature.

I know that's not common practice, but it has (again) saved my bacon on this occasion. For those who don't do this, making a backup of the `lxd.db` file would be advised.

EDIT : Further reading at https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/13/lxd-2-0-remote-hosts-and-container-migration-612/ shows that it is also very easy to use a remote LXD host and simply move conatiners between hosts.

This isn't the solution for me, in this particular instance, but it is a very good read showing a very easy way to migrate containers.

Comment: You could probably also `lxd image import` the images you want to re-use into your separate db.

Comment: That wouldn't work really, as I want to use one of my containers, not one of the images the container was built from. I did find out I can export a container as an image, re-import that image, then make a new container from it but that just seemed a bit of a faf. I wonder if there is a way to simply export/import containers ?

Comment: There is, if your LXD version is higher than 2.7. If so, the container's storage contains a .ymal which allows importing it to a new db.

Comment: Great. Could you tell me how it works or give me a link to a how to ?

Comment: As I am using the same PC, with the same large storage drive, just with a newly installed OS, I think my own answer is still correct (for me, in this instance). However, reading the answer from Jonathan Y prompted me to check out the LXD website (again) and I did see that remote hosts can be copied and moved very easily, so I have added an edit to my answer.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how lxd import works? The instructions are extremely unclear and I can't find out how to do it. I want to use lxd import, and NOT one of the other ways. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since my comments contain some typos, I'll recap a couple of suggestions for importing an existing container (whose storage is available) into a new DB.

First, there are (arguably) easier alternatives if one wants to copy an entire instance of LXD (by basically taking the storage of all containers, plus the DB from `/var/lib/lxd`). Also, if the old instance is still running and reachable by network, a more native approach is to define it as a remote as described in the [Remote hosts and container migration](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/13/lxd-2-0-remote-hosts-and-container-migration-612/) chapter in the wonderful Ubuntu Insights [LXD 2.0: Blog post series](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/03/14/the-lxd-2-0-story-prologue/).

---

Now, one approach described in [another chapter of that series](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/01/lxd-2-0-image-management-512/) (again, only feasible if the old instance is still running) is to make an image of an existing container using

```
lxc publish <my-container>@<snapshot> <my-image-name>
```

then export it to tarballs with

```
lxc image export <my-image-name> /path/to/directory
```

The resulting tarballs can be imported with

```
lxc image import <metadata-tarball> <rootfs-tarball> --alias <my-image-name>
```

---

As OP said in comments, that's quite a bit of work. What's more serious is that it fails if for some reason you can't run the old instance.

As of version 2.7 LXD stores a `backup.yaml` file inside each container's storage (at `/var/lib/lxd/containers/<my-container>`) which allows importing a container from a copy, using `lxd import` (see [LXD Backup Strategies](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/backup.md) and this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/2954)). Note the `lxd`; this is different from `lxc image import`.

Based on the [LXD News page](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/news/) I presume one does that by simply moving a container's storage into the `/var/lib/lxd/containers` directory, and running

```
lxd import <my-container>
```

However, as Xenial official repositories currently offer version 2.0.9 of LXD, I haven't tested that last part.

Comment: That's not how you're supposed to use lxd import. I tried it and it doesn't work. Have you figured a way to use it?

Comment: @alexk I'm not sure, although: (a) this will only work on LXD 2.7 or higher, and (b) see the provided link. If your version is higher than 2.7, then perhaps `lxd import --help` might steer you in the right direction? Please edit this answer if you find the way it's meant to be run. (Or post the error message in a comment.)

Comment: There's progress in the discussion here, about this topic: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/3479